# How Do I set this PHP printed HTML form to stay within <p> tags?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, tags

So I'm building a fairly simple login page for my website.
Only the login form, an HTML form printed by PHP `echo` commands, doesn't want to stay in the HTML `<p></p>` tags.
Here's the code:

```
<div ID="loginbox"><p> 
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect( $dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass ) or die("Cannot connect to the server");?>

<?php      
if($_SESSION['authenticated']) { //// See if the user's logged in 
echo "You are logged in as $name "; //// If they are show message  
} else { //// if not logged show login form 
echo '<form action="login.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log"> '; 
echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="name" />';
echo '<br /> Password: <input type="password" name="password" />';
echo '<br /> <input type="submit" value="Login" />'; 
echo '</form><br />';
echo '<a href="registeruser.php">Don&#146;t have a login? click here to register</a>'; 
}
?>                
</p>
</div>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
#loginbox {
border-radius: 15px;
color: black;
position:inherit;
width: 250px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 55px;
}
#loginbox  > p {
border-radius: 15px;
background-color:white;
box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
height:387px;
Width:500px;
top:60px;
left:50px;
font-family: palatino;
padding:50px 50px 37.5px 37.5px;}

#loginbox > form {    position: inherit;
z-index: 3;
top: 150px;
padding-left: 36px;
margin: 0 auto;}


#loginbox a:visited
{color:#010101;}

#loginbox a:hover
{color:#010101;}

#loginbox a:active
{color:#000000;}
```

[**And click here to see how it looks in-browser**](http://sam-third.co.uk/m201/oliver/login.php)

Comment: is the P tag started? I only see the closing P tag.

Comment: also, i would put my connect-to-db-line in a separate file `connect_to_db.php`, and then `include`/`require` that file at the very top of every php-script that needs to connect to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form>` elements are not allowed inside `<p>` elements.  Your browser sees this invalid code and decides that the best way to rectify the issue is to pretend that the `<p>` has ended before the `<form>` starts.

If you replace the `<p>` with a `<div>`, your code will do what you want.

Comment: Swapped the CSS that governed that particular `<p></p>` tag to it's own CSS class, then swapped out the p tag for a Div tag with the ID of said CSS.

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem:

> The main error is that a `<p>` isn't allowed to contain non-inline
>   content. You can either remove the `<p>` and `[</p>][1]` completely,
>   or, move them inside the `<form>`.
>
> As for 'why', it's because that's how it's defined in the schema which
>   defines what is and what is not valid XHTML. If you look at this
>   section of the [XHTML definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml-modularization-20010410/abstract_modules.html#s_textmodule) you'll see that `<p>` is only
>   allowed to contain text or 'inline' (not 'block') tags. However a
>   `<form>` counts as 'block' content not as 'inline' content.
>
> In other words, a form can contain paragraphs, but a paragraph cannot
>   contain forms.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll replace the P tag with a div tag.

Answer (score 0):

I see `<p>` tag opened and closed before `<form>` tag and another `<p>` tag opened and closed after `</form>` tag in browser.

`<p>` tags are for formatting only text content. Use `<div>` tags instead of `<p>` tags.

Comment: Are you looking to source code or console formatted code? Because console html is closed and opened correctly, even when it's missing some tag part.

Comment: Console formatted code. Yes, I meant about the browser rendering of the code.